# Unable to import ResNet18 from image-classifiers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I wanted to explore ResNet18 for audio classification but I am unable to import it.

I have tried the following ways, but all of them are giving me errors:

```
from classification_models import Classifiers
# Error: ImportError: cannot import name 'Classifiers'

from classification_models.resnet import ResNet18, preprocess_input
# Error: from classification_models.resnet import ResNet18, preprocess_input  

from classification_models.keras import Classifiers
# Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classification_models.keras'
```

I have tried the above methods using [this link](https://github.com/qubvel/classification_models) but in vain.

Please help me to install ResNet18 successfully.

Comment: have you installed the `classification_models` package? As written in the instruction you pointed: `from classification_models.keras import Classifiers; ResNet18, preprocess_input = Classifiers.get('resnet18')`

Comment: Yes, I have installed it.